# textbox text changed event to check the user existed in our database or not

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have to validate the text box with username, if the username is not existed in our database it has to display one error message. i want to do it with using java script.

I have tried with using auto post back method.

I don't have any idea, how to use java script for this, pls do help

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656652/check-if-username-exists-in-a-asp-net-form?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it out.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "script.aspx",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id : menuId },
    sucess: funxtion(ispresent){if(ispresent)
    {alert('data is present');    
        } 
    else{alert('data is not present');    

    });
```